# Is this piece of code SQL Injection safe?

Tags: java

Does this prevent SQL injection or do I have to pass the parameter with `preparedStatement.setString()`

```
String sqlQuery = "select st from master where st_id= %1s ";

sqlQuery = String.format(sqlQuery, id);
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

This is not a code review, the code above is an example for the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: What type does id has? if its a string we can inject stuff

Comment: If you want to make this injection safe, you need to get rid of the String.format and use the setString or whatever method you need relative to your datatype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are directly embedding user input in SQL code right here:

```
String.format(sqlQuery, id)
```

Effectively running user input *as code*.  So, no, this is **not safe** from SQL injections.  This is the definition of SQL injections.

Instead of directly embedding user input into the SQL code, use parameters in a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to treat user input as *values* rather than as *code*.  Essentially the query would become this:

```
String sqlQuery = "select st from master where st_id= ? ";
```

Then you'd use the tooling in the language to add the parameter value to the query:

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id); // <--- here
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

---

Side note: Some may point out that if `id` is a non-string type then this code would still be safe from SQL injections, because nobody could inject anything *dangerous* as a number for example.  While that may be *circumstantially* true for any given instance of this, it's not guaranteed and still not safe practice.

Always treat user input as values, not as code.  Regardless of the type of that input or how sure you may otherwise be of the source of that input.  Don't give an attacker any avenue of attack, even if you can't think of any way in which they can exploit it.